# Problem with querying sql server from vb

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Whenever I have

```
Dim catID as integer
```

And I use this in a query like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from categories where parentid='" + catID + "'"
```

I get:

> Conversion from string `select * from categories where p` to type `Double` is not valid.

Why is it so?
The `parentid` datatype in sql is `integer`.

Comment: Try this: cmd.CommandText = "select * from categories where parentid='" + catID.ToString() + "'"
Also, just a thought: you are specifying catid for parentid... does your above query runs if in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Please always use parametrized queries, NEVER string concatenation.

Comment: Where is this error message coming from?  I doubt it is SQL Server because a Double datatype is called a Float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
cmd.CommandText = string.Format("select * from categories where parentid='{0}'", catID)
```

if `parentid` is a numeric field in your database then you'll need

```
cmd.CommandText = string.Format("select * from categories where parentid={0}", catID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove single quotes:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from categories where parentid=" + catID.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was telling you that it couldn't add "SELECT *..." with your catID value.  The '+' operator tried to convert "SELECT *..." into a number so it could do math on it, but it couldn't, so it threw the error.

A lot of people try to use '+' for string concatenation.  This is not the best practice because '+' will only concatenate when both sides are strings.  But if it finds a number on one side (as in your case, with catID), then it will try to do math instead of concat.

Best practice to just make a habit to never use '+' to concat strings; always use '&' instead.  That way you don't have to think about it.

I.e.:

```
1+1 = 2
1+A = error
1&1 = 11
1&A = 1A
```

Comment: BTW -- the other comments about paramaterizing your queries are important.  Can be dangerous, the way you're doing it, as far as risking injection goes.

Comment: its a inhouse application so no worries about that :) ,btw the tip was great i will remember it now :)